# Specify a GPU to use at launch

Tags: azure, nvidia, grid

I am currently working with an Azure GPU VM (NV6 using M60 Nvidia Graphic card)
I'm doing my benchmark on this VM without any issue for the moment.
Now I'm doing the same benchmark on a NV12 which has 2 GPU (or at least Windows server sees it as 2 GPUs).

I would like to launch my app twice with each app having its own GPU.
I'm a bit lost where to look to specify a GPU to a program. Is it a Windows configuration/poweshell script, is it a Nvidia Grids configuration to setup or do I have to add some code in my app to choose which GPU it has to use ?

Thank you,